# How to select first element in select list Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have select list with options:

```
  <select ng-model="yr[$index]" ng-selected="year.id == 'I'" ng-options="year.id as year.id for year in years">
    </select>
```

How to select first element in select list, where element is string?
My code is:

http://plnkr.co/edit/U4Fxh0JSxxtwhJWT9opG?p=preview

Comment: The code in the plunkr is completely different from the one posted in the question. Make up your mind. Anyway, since ng-model contains the selected item, and is used for two-way binding, you just need to initialize `formData.beginYearEnd[$index]` to the ID of the first year.

Comment: Now is right. I updated question

Comment: No, it isn't. The plunkr has 2 selects, and none of them is the one posted in the question.

Comment: All example in plunkr, there that I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write another variable is called `currentYear` as the following:

```
$scope.currentYear = $scope.years[0];
```

And Your select as the following:

```
 <select ng-model="currentYear" ng-options="year.id disable when (year.id < yr[$index]) for year in years">
</select>
```

**After Update**

To display the value, you can add the select as the following:

```
<select ng-model="currentYear.value" ng-options="year.value as year.value for year in years">
</select>
```

Comment: just add `currentYear` in your `$scope`, and put it as `ng-model`, I tied it, and it's working well ?

Comment: Need set `$scope.currentYear =  $scope.years[0].id;`, it works, but instead symbol `I` I see `0` in select list. http://plnkr.co/edit/TTN5JmLbMbtiyShGgcSx?p=preview

Comment: You didn't change `ng-options` value .. I wrote `ng-options="year.value as year.value for year in years"` .. so change `year.id` to `year.value`

Comment: Thanks you. Excellent solution!

Comment: How I can set `$index` for model `$scope.currentYear `? Like as: $scope.currentYear[$index]?

Comment: you can do it by developing function is called `changeCurrentYear($index)`, and call it by `ng-change`, then in this function change the value of `currentYear`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :  ng-init="something  = options[0]"

[You can read about it here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: Does not work. I tried: `ng-init="yr[$index] = years[0]"`

Comment: ng-init is explicitely documented as bad practice, except for a single use-case. Put that code in the controller, where it belongs.

Comment: Agree with using the controller for code, makes things much easier.